# Jasmine test promise in controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I can't seem to figure out how to get the  " - Generate POD returns a PDF File' Spec. Jasmine times out before any return happens so I am unable to test. When I take out the done callback function then the test runs fine but I suspect that it is a false positive.

**Controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app.controllers')
            .controller('podController', podController);

        podController.$inject = ['podService','$window'];

        function podController(podService,$window) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.generatePOD = generatePOD;
            vm.downloadPDF = downloadPDF;
            vm.openPDF = openPDF;

            /////////////

            function downloadPDF(willCallId){
                var fileName = 'pod-' + willCallId;
                generatePODFile(willCallId).then(function(file){
                    openPDF(file,fileName);
                });
            }

            function generatePOD(willCallId) {
                return podService.getPOD(willCallId).then(function(data){
                    var byteCharacters = atob(data);
                    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                    var file = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                    return file;
                });
            }

            function openPDF(file,fileName){
                var fileURL = $window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $window.open(fileURL,fileName);
            }
        }
})();
```

**Service**

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';
        angular
            .module('app.services')
            .service('podService', podService);

        podService.$inject = ['IEHRestangular'];

        function podService(IEHRestangular) {

                var service = {
                    getPOD: getPOD
                };

                return service;

                ///////////////////////

                function getPOD(willCallId) {
                    return IEHRestangular.one('/ClientEventNotification/api/POD/').customGET('GetPOD', {'willcallid': willCallId},{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then(function (data) {
                        return data;
                    });
                }
            }

})();
```

**Controller Test Suite**

```
describe('POD Controller Test', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    }));


    var $controller,$window,podService,$q,vm,deferred;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_,$window,_podService_,$q,$timeout){
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $window = $window;
        $timeout = $timeout;
        podservice = _podService_;
        $q = $q;
        vm = $controller('podController', {'$window': $window, podservice:podService});
    }));


    it(' - Generate POD returns a PDF File', function (done) {
        var willcallid = 3265987;
        deferred.resolve('resolveData');
        spyOn(podservice, 'getPOD').and.returnValues(deferred.promise);
        vm.generatePOD(willcallid).then(function(data){
            expect(data).toBe((data instanceof Blob));
            expect(podservice.getPOD).toHaveBeenCalledWith(willcallid);
done();
        });
    });

    it(' - Opens a window displaying a PDF File', inject( function( $window ) {
        spyOn( $window, 'open' ).and.callFake( function() {
            return true;
        } );
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(1024);
        var file = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        vm.openPDF(file,'testFile');
        expect( $window.open ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    } ) );

});
```

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

When using `ngMock` many services are replaced by versions that can be controlled in a synchronous manner, to give more control over the flow during tests. This means that in many cases you don't need to use the Jasmine `done` callback.

It's also important to know that promises are tied to the digest cycle, which means a promise's `then`, `catch` and `finally` callbacks are only executed after a digest has run.

You don't need many changes:

```
it(' - Generate POD returns a PDF File', function() {

  var willcallid = 3265987;

  spyOn(podservice, 'getPOD').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

  vm.generatePOD(willcallid).then(function (data) {

    expect(podservice.getPOD).toHaveBeenCalledWith(willcallid);
    expect(data instanceof Blob).toBe(true);
  });

  deferred.resolve('resolveData');

  // Trigger the digest loop and resolution of promise callbacks
  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

What happened when you removed the `done` callback in your example was that the spec would run without any waiting, but the promise callback functions would never be executed, the expects would never be executed and the test would pass (since no exepcts outside the promise callback either).